# Run a single test from within module main

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose, sage

Suppose I have `myclass_test.py` with [Nose](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) tests with following lines:

```py
import nose

class TestMyClass:
    def test_method(self):
        assert true

    def test_another_method(self):
        assert true

if __name__ == "__main__":
    nose.runmodule()
```

So I can run `python myclass_test.py` and have all of my tests to pass. Everything work as expected.

What should I pass to [runmodule](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/core.html#nose.core.runmodule)() to run a single test (for example `test_method`)?

If it is impossible with Nose is it possible with some other unit-test framework on the same manner (with runner inside module)?

P.S. I actually run not `python myclass_test.py` but `sage myclass_test.sage`. These are [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/) interpreter and SageMath file. SageMath code is basically Python code and `myclass_test.sage` is finally [preparsing](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/developer/coding_in_python.html#sage-preparsing) to `myclass_test.sage.py` and run with embedded to Sage Python interpreter.

So it isn't recognizable as module by Python interpreter so passing something like `sage myclass_test.sage TestMyClass.test_method` or `sage myclass_test.sage myclass_test.sage:TestMyClass.test_method` or `sage myclass_test.sage myclass_test.sage.py:TestMyClass.test_method` isn't working (by the same reason one [cannot directly import sage file as module](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/7867/importing-sage-files/?answer=48947#post-id-48947)). Even though Nose passing `argv` to `runmodule()` automatically.

P.P.S. Also I cannot use external runner like `nosetests -q -s sage myclass_test.sage:TestMyClass.test_method`.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used nose, but here is a possibility to do it with unittest:

```
import unittest

class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_method(self):
        assert True

    def test_another_method(self):
        assert True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestSuite([TestMyClass('test_method')])
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

And here is the same with pytest:

```
import pytest

class TestMyClass:
    def test_method(self):
        assert True

    def test_another_method(self):
        assert True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main([f'{__file__}::TestMyClass::test_method'])
```

Ok, I also checked with nose, and this seems to work:

```
import nose
from nose.suite import ContextSuite

class TestMyClass:
    def test_method(self):
        assert True

    def test_another_method(self):
        assert True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = ContextSuite([TestMyClass.test_method])
    nose.runmodule(suite=suite)
```

though the output is strange - while it certainly runs the test, it says "Ran 0 tests".

Comment: Works as you sad. But not so good with SageMath because it doesn't load some libraries or may be doesn't do some preparsing. Works fine with python but there is no evidence of running in case test is passed.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't help you here. Both pytest and nose load a lot of stuff (plugins, hook) on start, unittest not so much. Have you tried using unittest?